# TightVNC - shareapp and sharewindow options

Tags: command-line, window, share, vnc

Could anyone please give me command line examples of how to run TightVNC to share a specific app and a specific window? (trying this on Windows 7)

I keep getting "Failed to connect to TightVNC server" no matter what I do.

Also, what is the difference between running with "controlservice" and "controlapp"?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 3):

**Server side** do:

```
"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnserver.exe"  -run
"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnserver.exe"  -controlapp -shareapp <app PID>
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnserver.exe"  -run
"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnserver.exe"  -controlapp -sharewindow Calculator
```

To find your application PID you can use `tasklist` and, if you have a grep-like command:

```
tasklist  | grep <app name>
```

**Viewer side**:

Run your viewer as usual.

Comment: can we use -sharerect and -shareapp together? and if we run the sharepp command 2 times. will it work for both or for the last one?

Comment: it a bit confusing for me.sharewindow seems to be not working correctly